Custom data validation that locks the cell as per the value in the other cell
My question is related to the custom data validation that locks the cell as per the value in the other cell.
I have two data columns (R4:R1000 and U4:U1000). My question is, if we enter “Open” in cell range R, then unlock the specific cell in column “U” and open drop down with Yes & No. If we have “Close” in cell range “R”, then specific cell in column “U” should restrict the value entry and move the cursor to column “V”. Basically, column “U” value is based on Column “R”. This should apply throughout whole range (R4:R1000 and U4:U1000).
I Tried this script but it wont work:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K2:K1000")) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("G2:G1000").Value = "Open" Then
            ActiveCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="Yes,No"
            Else
            Worksheets("sheets1").Unprotect
            Worksheets("sheets1").Range("K2:K1000").Locked = True
            Worksheets("sheets1").Protect
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Target, Range("K2:K1000")) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("sheets1").Unprotect
    End If
End Sub


"it wont work" isn't a very useful description of what exactly happens or doesn't happen when you run your code.  If Range("G2:G1000").Value = "Open" doesn't match your description of the columns you're working with, and you can't compare the value of a multi-cell range (a 2D array) with "Open"

Maybe something like this:
'you want worksheet_change not _selectionchange
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cellU As Range
    'some initial checks on Target...
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("R2:R1000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Set cellU = Target.Offset(0, 3) 'col U on same row
    
    Me.Unprotect 'use `Me` to refer to the worksheet
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Open"
            With cellU
                .Locked = False      'unlock cell
                .Validation.Delete
                .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="Yes,No"
            End With
        Case "Close"
            cellU.Validation.Delete
            cellU.Locked = True
        Case Else
            'what to do if (eg) blank?
    End Select
    Me.Protect 'reprotect sheet
End Sub

